# How to calculate the right motor size & type for a soil sifter?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors

**How would one calculate the proper size of an electric motor to properly drive a soil sifter?**

**Assumptions:**
**Screen:**  flat, 18"x24", 1/4" to 3/4" wire cloth (interchangeable screens), total weight (including frame) = 4 lbs
**Shake Info:** total screen movement/shake = 6", shake rate = 132 shakes per minute
**Load:**  15 lbs soil or gravel mix
**Other:** Belt driven

**Note:**  I'd hate to use a 3/4 hp motor when all I might need is a 1/50 hp motor.

Comment: Depends on the geometry and any gearing involved (a beltwheel connected to a different size beltwheel is a gearing)

Comment: Would you give me an example of what you mean exactly?